# How to delete all selected checkbox value and there particular row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a table which has only title field. I  am not using ID field in this table as its not required. 
Now on my front page i have a grid view which display title and there is a column item template check box. 
I want to delete all selected checkbox value and there particular row.
How to do it.?
Anybody can suggest me that...
Thanks In advance... 
i am doing..

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        grdlistWord.
        ArrayList arr;
        if (ViewState["TotalRecords"] != null)
        {
            arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["TotalRecords"];
        }
        else
        {
            arr = new ArrayList();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < grdlistWord.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grdlistWord.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkWord");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                if (!arr.Contains(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    arr.Add(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (arr.Contains(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value))
                {
                    arr.Remove(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value);
                }
            }
            //}
        }
        ViewState["TotalRecords"] = arr;
    }

    protected void lnkbtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                //SetData();
                //gvAll.AllowPaging = false;
                //gvAll.DataBind();
                ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["TotalRecords"];
                count = arr.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < grdlistWord.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //string a = grdlistWord.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    //Response.Write(a.ToString());
                    if (arr.Contains(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value))
                    {

                        DeleteRecord(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString());
                        arr.Remove(grdlistWord.DataKeys[i].Value);
                    }
                }
                ViewState["TotalRecords"] = arr;
                //hfCount.Value = "0";
                //gvAll.AllowPaging = true;
                GridBind();
                //ShowMessage(count);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }


    private void DeleteRecord(string word)
    {

        string query = "delete from searchword where word=@word";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

HTML Code:

Word:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>List</legend>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdlistWord" runat="server" DataKeyNames="word" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="grdlistWord_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdlistWord_RowDeleting" Width="456px" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWord" runat="server" onclick="check_click(this);" OnCheckedChanged="chkWord_CheckedChanged" />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="lnkbtnDelete_Click" ForeColor="white"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Word" HeaderText="Word" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Edit" Text="edit" DataNavigateUrlFields="Word" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SearchWord.aspx?words={0}&amp;mode=Edit" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderText="Delete" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>Records not exist!</EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCount" runat="server" Value = "0" />

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: [LMGTFY](http://tinyurl.com/3u4loqq)

Comment: @Tr1stan I do not want to do with id. can u tell without using id

Comment: @divya: OK, then what are you using to uniquely identify the row? Name? Seeing your code would really help.

Comment: @Tr1stan : I did not uniquely indentifing row.here is my code..

Comment: Can you send the HTML as well ?

Comment: @divya: What problems are you having?

Comment: @Pankaj : i have posted HTML code ..

Comment: @Tr1stan:It is not deleting any row in grid view.

Comment: @divya: I had guessed that :) Have you tried stepping through your code to see where your code gets to and where you think it might be failing?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/04/delete-multiple-rows-gridview-checkbox.html) looks like it has an answer for you - difficult to say though with the limited amount of info you've give in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the CheckedChanged event of the CheckBox and retrieve the corresponding title value in that row. Then write SQL code to delete all rows in the table whose title equals this title value. Use ExecuteNonQuery with the SqlCommand object to run this statement and perform the deletion.

Comment: I do not want to delete row on checked changed event.I want to delete selected record on the button click event.